# Openssl decode of encrypted file does not work anymore

Tags: debian, 64-bit, openssl

I recently updated my computer to 64 bit Debian testing. Since then, decryption of files that were encrypted with openssl on 32 bit Debian does not work anymore.

I used to encrypt files like so:

```
$ openssl des3 -in bla.txt -out bla.txt.des3
```

and decrypt like this:

```
$ openssl des3 -d -in bla.txt.des3 -out bla.txt
```

This still works if I chroot into a backup of the old 32 bit Debian testing installation. On the 64 bit install, I get the following error:

```
$ openssl des3 -d -in bla.txt.des3 -out bla.txt
enter des-ede3-cbc decryption password:
bad decrypt
140219224302720:error:06065064:digital envelope outines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:529:
```

Which is the correct way to invoke `openssl` on the 64 bit Debian testing system to decode the files?

**EDIT** version information:

old (32-bit in chroot):

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
$ dpkg -l | grep ssl
ii  libssl1.0.2:i386                                            1.0.2j-1                             i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  openssl                                                     1.0.2j-1                             i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  ssl-cert                                                    1.0.38                               all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl
  linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7729000)
  libssl.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2 (0xf769c000)
  libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 (0xf7498000)
  libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7493000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf72dc000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x5663b000)
```

new (64-bit):

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016
$ dpkg -l | grep ssl
ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                                           1.0.2j-4                          amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.1:amd64                                             1.1.0c-2                          amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  openssl                                                     1.1.0c-2                          amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  ssl-cert                                                    1.0.38                            all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe63c76000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f9b74487000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f9b73ff6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9b73df2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9b73bd5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9b73837000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a182164000)
```

Comment: 32-bit and 64-bit is not really useful. What is the old version of Debian and OpenSSL; and what is the new version of of Debian and OpenSSL?

Comment: I added what I hope is the relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the default for the message digest has changed from md5 to sha-256 in OpenSSL 1.1.0. Decrypting stuff using the old digest remains possible, if you make it explicit:

```
openssl des3 -d -in bla.txt.des3 -out bla.txt -md md5
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Your answer helped me decrypt an old ethereum wallet I encrypted when the default was `md5`!